# Created cpanel git repo But whenever I cloning its nothing download any root data just empty folder with .git

Tags: git, cpanel, clone, atlassian-sourcetree, git-clone

I have created repo in cPanel git version tool. Whenever I clone this repo data locally by using ssh command it's always cloning empty folder data. But I want to clone all my site data from "public_html" folder.

My .cPanel.yml code:

```
---
deployment:
  tasks:
    - export DEPLOYPATH=/home/user/public_html/
    - /bin/cp -R * $DEPLOYPATH
```

Its always cloning empty folder from cPanel repo. Can anyone please suggest is how I can clone complete my site root data.

Thanks in advance